# How to cleanup the "Found in build" dropdown in TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This dropdown (in bug work item) lists *every* build ever made for the team project.. even when I delete the builds en check of the boxes for deletion, this list still lists all builds.

How can I shorten is list to only existing builds? or is something wrong and should they be deleted automatically (with deleting the build)?

This is the same for the "integrated in build" field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Process Template Editor (available in the [TFS 2010 Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)) which allows you to edit the global lists that contain the information for the suggested values displayed in the build fields on a work item.

Once you have the Power Tools installed, you can open up Visual Studio and navigate to the Global List editor(s):

```
Tools --> Process Editor --> Global List --> (Several options available)
```

The quickest way will be to export the list to a text file, edit it however you want, and then import the last back in which will overwrite the existing list.

You could automate this as well by creating a TFS Job and using the TFS SDK to clean out any unwanted builds from the list.